# How to dynamically set max_execution_time based on file size in php

Tags: php, laravel, filestream

I have a job in Laravel which downloads .zip files from an ftp-server to the local disk using the Laravel file-system. The sizes of those files vary between a few MB and up to multiple GB.

This is my current code which works fine, as long as I increase the `max_execution_time`:

```
public function handle()
{
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
    $destination = storage_path('app/temp/' . $this->import->unique_filename);

    $ftpDisk = Storage::disk($this->import->disk);

    $stream = $ftpDisk
        ->getDriver()
        ->readStream($this->import->filename);

    file_put_contents($destination, stream_get_contents($stream), FILE_APPEND);        
}
```

Is there a possibility to chunk the downloaded file in smaller pieces? Or another option which is better than setting the max_execution_time to maximum?

Another approach would be to extract the archive on the ftp server and read the content (csv/json and images) file by file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not recommended to change the maximum execution time during the execution of the job. instead, you can dispatch the job into a [queue](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues) to run time-consuming tasks such as downloading.

then you can run queue worker command followed by *--timeout=0*.

```
php artisan queue:listen --timeout=0
```

Comment: But does this affect the max execution time of the underlying php runtime? The queue worker will run the maximum time set by the flag `--timeout=0`. And the job itself? Isn't it plain php which would take the default value from `max_execution_time`?